# Error when using Bibtex

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I have the example

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \vspace{-0.4em}
    \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
    \renewcommand{\section}[2]{\vskip 0.05em}
\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

where 'sample.bib' is,

```
@BOOK{Wilkinson:2012qr,
    title={{S}tochastic {M}odelling for {S}ystems {B}iology},
    publisher = {Taylor {\&} Francis Group},
    author = {Darren J. Wilkinson},
    year ={2012},
    edition = {2nd},
}
```

And for some reason when I try run this I'm getting an error saying 'I couldn't open style file ieee.bst' but I'm not using this file type?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the `.aux` and then rerunning latex,bibtex,latex,latex

Comment: How would I do this, sorry I'm new to latex

Comment: *How* to go about deleting the aux files depends both on your computer system and your TeX distribution. You haven't exactly been chatty about those details. Please do tell us which TeX distribution and which front-end editing program you employ.

Comment: @Mico If I knew what you were talking about obviously I would specify those details. I'm not trying to be cryptic, I genuinely am just having an issue I know nothing about.

Comment: @Gragbow - Which front end (an editor and interface to the TeX distribution) do you employ? E.g., winedt, texworks, texshop, texstudio, or some other program?

Comment: Off-topic: There should be no need to encase the uppercase letters in the `title` field, or the `&` character in the `publisher` field, in curly braces.

Comment: The most likely reason for getting the errror message `couldn't open style file ieee.bst` is that your document, at some point in the (probably not too distant past) contained the instruction `\bibliographystyle{ieee}`; if the system can't find the file `ieee.bst`, it will issue the preceding error message.

Answer (score 3):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

If you use a "front end" (i.e, some editor program) that interfaces with your TeX distribution, it should provide a method deleting the so-called auxiliary files (those with extension aux, blg, log, bbl, etc). For example, if you're using `TeXworks`, click on the "File" button in the top-row ribbon, and select "Remove Aux Files...". Then, recompile from scratch.

Here's the output from a simplified and streamlined version of your sample code.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
%% create 'sample.bib' on the fly:
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.bib}
@BOOK{Wilkinson:2012qr,
    title    ={Stochastic Modelling for Systems Biology},
    publisher={Taylor~\& Francis Group},
    author   ={Darren J. Wilkinson},
    year     ={2012},
    edition  ={2nd},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{sample}
\end{document}
```